# I want my code to create grid made of blocks with input amount of rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2x number input and function which should create grid with x rows and y columns but when I click the button nothing happens.

The full code:

```js
var ground = document.getElementById("ground")
  function getHV() {
  var x = Number(document.getElementById("h").value);
  var y = Number(document.getElementById("v").value);
  for (y; y > 0; y--) {
  for (x; x > 0; x--) {
    blocks = "block" + x;
    blocks = document.createElement("div");
    ground.appendChild(blocks);
    blocks.backgroundcolor = "black";
    blocks.style.height = 50 + "px";
    blocks.style.width = 50 + "px";
    };
  } 
}
```

```css
#ground {
background-color: lightblue;
width:345px;
height:450px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="h" value="10"/>
<input type="number" id="v" value="10"/>
<button id="submit" onclick="getHV();">Submit</button>
<div id="ground"></div>
```

Comment: x and y are strings. You need to convert it... `Number(document.getElementById("h").value);`

Comment: Converted and still doesnt do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x and y are strings. You need to convert them to numbers, however once you use `x--` it gets converted to a number anyway.

You have some logic issues, but in general it works... they're just invisible.

```js
var ground = document.getElementById("ground")

function getHV() {
  let x = Number(document.getElementById("h").value);
  let y = Number(document.getElementById("v").value);
  for (y; y > 0; y--) {
    for (x; x > 0; x--) {
      const block = document.createElement("div");
      block.innerText = "block" + x;
      block.backgroundcolor = "black";
      block.style.height = 50 + "px";
      block.style.width = 50 + "px";
      ground.appendChild(block);
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="h" value="10" />
<input type="number" id="v" value="10" />
<button id="submit" onclick="getHV();">Submit</button>
<div id="ground"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `document.getElementById("h").value` return a string, so you need to convert it to `Number`

2) use a `blocks.style.backgroundColor` property for set a background

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #ground {
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 345px;
            height: 450px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="h" value="10"/>
<input type="number" id="v" value="10"/>
<button id="submit" onclick="getHV();">Submit</button>
<div id="ground"></div>
<script>
  var ground = document.getElementById('ground');

  function getHV() {
    var x = Number(document.getElementById('h').value);
    var y = Number(document.getElementById('v').value);

    for (y; y > 0; y--) {
      for (x; x > 0; x--) {
        blocks = 'block' + x;
        blocks = document.createElement('div');
        ground.appendChild(blocks);
        blocks.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        blocks.style.height = 50 + 'px';
        blocks.style.width = 50 + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you just add Number()? Because it still doesnt do anything